# Graphs of maximum diameter of prescribed degree sequence.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I have two questions, both inspired by [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4761454/837198), where it is asked what the maximum diameter a graph on $2023$ vertices and minimum degree 42 is. The answer is 140, which is approximately $\frac{3n}{\delta+1}$ where $n$ is the number of vertices and $\delta$ is the minimum degree, and it is achieved by a sequence of small and big cliques put on a path. I believe the same construction works for general $n$ and $\delta$, if we require all vertices to have degree at least $\delta$.

My questions are:

1. Given a sequence of integers $A = a_1, \dots, a_n$, $a_i\geq a_{i+1}$, what can be said of the maximum diameter of a graph with degree sequence $D=d_1, \dots, d_n$, $d_i\geq d_{i+1}$, which dominates $A$, meaning $d_i\geq a_i$ for all $i$?
2. Are extremal graphs for the above question always of the form of a bunch of cliques glued on a path (as in the motivating post)?

Comment: I think that answers question 1. Does it answer question 2?

Comment: Sorry. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667571/upper-bound-of-graph-diameter-using-only-degree-of-vertices) is not the same. Your question permits degree greater than given values.

Comment: Well I'm quite sure it can't differ too much since the diameter should decrease by increasing degrees. It is quite relevant to my first question, so thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: For question 1, it might be challenging to establish a precise bound using  $a_1,a_2,\dots a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ represent an endpoint of the longest path within the graph. Denote $S_i$ as the set of vertices situated at a distance $i$ from $v$. If there's a pair of vertices in $S_i$ not connected by an edge, adding this edge preserves the graph's adherence to the degree condition without altering any $S_i$. The same goes for adding edge between $S_i$ and $S_{i+1}$. These adjustments demonstrate that the maximum diameter can be achieved at a form of "a bunch of cliques glued on a path".

Comment: Right, that is quite evident. Thanks!